# How to create a random partitioned data in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have the following data:

```
id INT name STRING

1     a
2     b
3     c
```

I want to create a new table in Hive with partition CountryID and load the data into the table and put random value in CountryID.

I'm using the following commands but it does not work:

```
Hive> set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict
Hive> CREATE TABLE test (id INT, name STRING) PARTITIONED BY (CountryID INT);
Hive> LOAD DATA INPATH '/my_data.txt' INTO TABLE test PARTITION (CountryID = rand());
```

I get the following error:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:76 cannot recognize input near 'rand' '(' ')' in constant
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do an insert overwrite

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE test PARTITION(CountryId)
SELECT id,name, rand() as CountryId
FROM my_data;
```

after you create an external table for your my_data.txt file.